# Reaction of primary amine with mixed acid anhydride

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, nucleophilic-substitution, amines

Is this reaction $\ce{S_N2}$ (because attack of nucleophile and removal of leaving group are not taking place in a single step)?

[image]

Which part of anhydride should form the substituted amide? If it is an $\ce{S_N2}$, then $\ce{CH3COO-}$ is a better leaving group but a more (alkyl) $\ce{e-}$ releasing group, $\ce{-C2H5}$ would destabilize the T.S.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reaction between anhydride and primary amine is by the Nucleophic addition-elimination mechanism (NOT by SN2).

**First step:** Nucleophilic addition step (Rate determining step):

The addition of amine to carbonyl center (at the most electrophilic carbonyl center and it should generate least sterically hindered intermediate) gives rise to a tetrahedral intermediate (4 groups bonded to the carbon center), which is influenced by steric hinderance. Therefore the attack of primary amine will prominently take place at -CH3 end carbonyl center which is more electrophilic and gives less sterically hindered intermediate.

**Second step:** Elimination step (fast step, not a rate determining):

The internal nucleophile (O- of earlier carbonyl) reverts back to generate the carbonyl center and propionate ion is eliminated.

Note: As the mechanism of reaction is not by SN2, therefore leaving group stability is not the sole criteria.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "sterically hindered intermediate". Steric hindrance is a *kinetic property* of a reaction, not a *thermodynamic property* of a molecule.

Comment: Then  "sterically hindered transition state or pathway" will be correct ?

Comment: Pathway seems like a better choice.